# WebSocket messages are not sent or received for about 30 seconds after device experiences small amount of packet loss

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, voip, wireless

I've been experimenting with bidirectional uncompressed audio transmission over a WebSocket connection using Node.js to proxy the audio data to and from another device. Each audio chunk is 100 ms long and has a bitrate of around 136 kbps (so each chunk is about 1.7 KB). It works great, even with high latency connections, on VPNs and with a weak 3G connection, except, when I move one of the devices just slightly behind a wall about 15 m away from the WiFi router, the audio packets are not sent or received anymore. The WiFi RSSI is still high. After moving back to line of sight with the WiFi router, no packets are received or sent until about 30 seconds have passed and then it returns to normal. I'd expect some delayed chunks due to the packet loss and retransmission, but I don't know why it takes so long for the WebSocket messages to start being sent again. It could be something to do with head-of-line blocking, but behind the wall, a TCP connection test shows:
`Download: 327 Mbps, Upload: 239 Mbps, Jitter: 0.39 ms, Packet Loss: 0%.`
 Those numbers seem to contradict my observations, and don't explain why the connection becomes dead for about 30 seconds. I've tested it on iOS 14 Safari, Chrome on Android, Chrome on macOS, and Firefox for macOS, and with different WiFi routers. It happens on all of them. I've also tested it on the local network as well as proxied through Cloudflare. Here is the relevant code:

```
connect();

function connect() {
    if (!recording) startRec(); // capture the microphone samples and send them
    console.log('listening...');
    audioCtxRX = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); // set the audio context on user interaction

    dualTone(10, 20, 400); // play a tone

    var chunkPlaying = false;
    ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.example.com/wss3/');
    initWS = true;
    ws.binaryType = 'blob';
    ws.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('Connection Opened');
    });
    ws.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        dt = true;
        console.log('####message####');
        console.log(event.data);
        var data = event.data;
        dataUsed += data.size / 1000000;
        dataSum = data.size;
        if (pb) {
            data.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
                console.log(buffer);
                var inpDat;
                if (depth == 1) { // 2 bytes per sample or 1 byte per sample
                    inpDat = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                } else {
                    inpDat = new Uint16Array(buffer);
                }
                var audioFloat32Array = new Float32Array(inpDat.length);
                for (let i = 0; i < inpDat.length; i++) {
                    audioFloat32Array[i] = inpDat[i] / (res / 2) - 1;
                }
                console.log(audioFloat32Array);
                var channels = 2;
                var frameCount = audioFloat32Array.length * compressionRatio;
                myArrayBuffer = audioCtxRX.createBuffer(1, frameCount, 48000); // RX buffer;
                var nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(0);
                let m = 0;
                let c = 0;
                let y2 = 0;
                let y1 = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                    let bv = 0;

                    // linear interpolation
                    // if (i%compressionRatio == 0){
                    //     bv = audioFloat32Array[Math.floor(i/compressionRatio)];
                    //     y1 = audioFloat32Array[Math.floor(i/compressionRatio)];
                    //     y2 = i/compressionRatio+1 > audioFloat32Array.length - 1 ? y1 : audioFloat32Array[Math.floor(i/compressionRatio)+1];
                    //     m = (y2 - y1) / compressionRatio;
                    //     c = y1 - m*(i%compressionRatio);
                    // } else {
                    //     bv = m*(i%compressionRatio) + c;
                    // }
                    // nowBuffering[i] = audioFloat32Array[bv];

                    // with no linear interpolation:
                    nowBuffering[i] = audioFloat32Array[Math.floor(i / compressionRatio)];
                }
                chunkID++;

                if (!chunkPlaying) {
                    if (missedC) {
                        missedC = false;
                        chunkPlaying = true;
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            chunkPlay();
                        }, chunkSec / 0.002); // wait for half the chunk size, so the receiving of chunks happen half-way through the playing of the current chunk
                    } else {
                        chunkPlay();
                    }
                }

                function chunkPlay() {
                    chunkPlaying = true;
                    lastChunkID = chunkID;
                    playSt = new Date().getTime();
                    lastRC = new Date().getTime();
                    var source = audioCtxRX.createBufferSource();
                    source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
                    source.connect(audioCtxRX.destination);
                    source.start();
                    source.onended = function () {
                        chunkPlaying = false;
                        if (chunkID != lastChunkID) {
                            // there is a new chunk, so play it right away
                            chunkPlay();
                            missedC = false;
                        } else {
                            // new chunk has not been sent
                            missedC = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
}


function startRec() { // capture the microphone samples and send them over the websocket connection
  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var rate = audioCtx.sampleRate;
  var resampfact = 0;
  var resampType = 0;
  if (rate < 40000 || rate > 60000) console.error('Unsupported input sample rate. Must be 40-60 kilosamples/s');
  if (rate < 48000) {
      resampType = 1;
      resampfact = Math.floor(rate / (48000 - rate));
      console.log('RESAMP FACTOR: ' + resampfact);
  } else if (rate > 48000) {
      resampType = 2; // not implemented yet
  }
  var stream;
  var recordedData = [];
  var startDate;

  var audioInput;
  var audioNode;
  var bufferSize = 4096;

  // reset any previous data
  recordedData = [];
  recordingLength = 0;
  recording = true;

  if (audioCtx.createJavaScriptNode) {
      audioNode = audioCtx.createJavaScriptNode(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  } else if (audioCtx.createScriptProcessor) {
      audioNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  } else {
      throw 'WebAudio not supported!';
  }

  audioNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(onMicrophoneCaptured)
      .catch(onMicrophoneError);
  function onMicrophoneCaptured(microphone) {
      stream = microphone;
      audioInput = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(microphone);
      audioInput.connect(audioNode);
      audioNode.onaudioprocess = onAudioProcess;
      startDate = new Date();
      sampleRate = audioCtx.sampleRate;
  }

  function stopRecording(callback) {
      // stop recording
      recording = false;
      // to make sure onaudioprocess stops firing
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => { track.stop(); });
      audioInput.disconnect();
      audioNode.disconnect();
      if (inCall) {
          init();
      }
  }

  function onMicrophoneError(e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert('Unable to access the microphone.');
  }

  var nSince = 0;
  function onAudioProcess(e) {
      if (!recording) {
          return;
      }
      let elm = Array.from(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
      recordedData.push.apply(recordedData, elm);
      duration = new Date().getTime() - startDate;
      let chunkLD = false;
      if (recordedData.length > Math.round(chunkSec * rate)) {
          if (resampType == 1) {
              for (let i = 0; i < recordedData.length; i++) {
                  if (i % resampfact == 0) {
                      recordedData.splice(i + 1, 0, recordedData[i]);
                  }
              }
          }
          startDate = new Date().getTime();
          if (depth == 1) { // 8-bit depth or 16-bit depth
              chunk = new Uint8Array(Math.floor(recordedData.length / compressionRatio));
          } else {
              chunk = new Uint16Array(Math.floor(recordedData.length / compressionRatio));
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < recordedData.length / compressionRatio; i++) {
              let sampAvg = 0;
              for (let p = 0; p < compressionRatio; p++) {
                  sampAvg += recordedData[i * compressionRatio + p];
              }
              sampAvg /= compressionRatio;

              let cv = (sampAvg + 1) * (res / 2);
              if (cv > res) cv = res;
              else if (cv < 0) cv = 0;
              chunk[i] = cv;
          }
          recordedData = [];
          ws.send(chunk.buffer);
      
      }
  }
}
```

I've also got this code in a setInterval() which reconnects the WebSocket connection when it is closed, but the WebSocket connection remains open when the problem occurs so connectToWSServer() isn't called:

```
if ((ws.readyState == 2 || ws.readyState == 3) && initWS) {
    if (pb) connectToWSServer(); // attempt to reconnect if disconnected
}
```

The Node.js server simply relays the WebSocket binary data between the clients.

What could be the cause of this? And if it is not fixable, would HTTP streams be more effective? WebRTC does not meet my requirements. Thanks.

EDIT: I have done some more testing. I've found that the issue still occurs when the WebSocket messages are much smaller, like 10 bytes and when they are sent at a slower rate like once per second. Starting the connection next to the router and then walking behind the wall causes the audio to stop working, but when starting the connection behind the wall it works. But even stranger, when the connection is started behind the wall, it works, but when it is brought closer to the router, it then cuts out! I'm so confused. Surely I don't have to create a new WebSocket each time the audio cuts out?

EDIT 2: I think I've figured out the cause. It has nothing to do with my code or the server or WebSockets. All the WiFi access points I tried were the same brand. I tried connecting to a Ubiquity AP and the problem was solved. No idea why the other routers did what they did though.
It's now working great. I can go much farther without the audio dropping out, and when it does drop out, when moving closer to the router again, it immediately starts working again. My guess, after further observation as to why this happens is that when the client's RSSI is too low or maybe if there are too many dropped packets, the WiFi router sends a frame asking the device to reconnect to the network, it then takes some time to reconnect, but is specific to the firmware of the problematic routers.

Comment: It's hard to know for sure what's going on. It's possible your device disconnects from WiFi and connects to LTE or 3G or something for a while when you move it behind that wall. That will stop data flow on your WebSocket connection until WiFi reconnects.  (Your device has a different IP address when it's on the cellular network.)  Try turning off data for your cellular network.and see what happens. Same for WiFi.

Comment: My phone was on airplane mode with WiFi turned on and it happens with laptops as well. The WiFi indicator shows 3 bars constantly. HTTP requests sent every second still work. It's really weird.

Comment: In my experience, it's necessary to put WebSocket reconnect logic into Javascript client and server code that will run robustly in devices that move around. That way if your device jumps from one network to  another your connection will drop and re-establish.  I've tested this with a Faraday-shield bag I bought from some paranoid-prepper web site. Put the device in the bag, force a disconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem I've found is that (ws.readyState == 2 || ws.readyState == 3) doesn't become true when the issue occurs because the socket remains open, just in a paused sort of state, so the only way to detect this state is if pings are sent and there is no response.

Comment: You're right. It's a notorious pain in the xxx neck.